# past tense, passive verb

Tags: verbs, past-tense, passive-voice

What is correct usage -- or correct semi-slang usage -- for verb in this sentence:

'he was a boy who got beat up often'

Answer (score 0):

How about:

<strike>"He was a boy who was beaten often."</strike>

*EDIT*

Based on Jim's point that *beaten* is ambiguous and John Lawler's comment about the requirement for slang usage, consider:

*"He was a boy who was beaten up often."*

If the requirements of slang mandate that *got* must be used in place of *was,* then so be it.

Comment: Usage needs to include past of 'beat up'; purpose is literary, not formal, with American/Western slang inflection preferred. So: 'he got beat up'  or 'he got beaten up' or 'he was beaten up'?

Comment: **Why "up"??** _______________

Comment: _Beat up_ is a phrasal verb with the completive _up_ particle; it means 'beat to submission' and refers to the results as well as the action. It's an idiom common with children. For the slang category you request, you're almost on the money; but some other lexical changes might improve it: _He was a kid that got beat up a lot._ That sounds normal to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you think that *"He got beat up."* is an improved version of *"He was beaten."* ?

Comment: I think it's an improved version of American/Western slang, as I said. The OP is writing a story and needs a particular register for dialog.

Comment: I think just plain *beaten* is ambiguous.  Does it mean he often lost in competitions? Does it mean his parents physically disciplined him, or does it mean that he got *beat up* by other kids?

Comment: In this context, "beaten" implies, to my ear, physical punishment by a parent, teacher, etc., or, less likely without additional context, "defeated."  "Beaten up" implies "by other children."  Removing "up" therefore changes the meaning significantly.